# iOS AlertView - Can it be made atomic so that background processes must wait?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uialertview

I've been trying to get a caption put on a photo when taking a picture with the camera loaded in my application. What it's doing is it takes the photo and then once I hit "Use Photo" to save it, it will save it before the user can save the caption they want. It will actually add that caption to the next photo you take. I can also set it so that it asks to enter to caption before taking the photo, but that is awkward.

It would help if I could add another action button to the camera, but I have no idea how I would do that.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

[self getUserCaption];//calls alertview to get caption from user

// Declare Variables
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;

// Process for saving an image
if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)== kCFCompareEqualTo) { //if it's an image

    editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                               UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; //Assign the edited image to editedImage
    originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                 UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; //Assign the original image to originalImage

    //Check to see if there was indeed an edited image, if so use that, otherwise use the original
    if (editedImage) {
        //imageToSave = editedImage;
        imageToSave = [self addCaption:editedImage];
    } else {
        //imageToSave = originalImage;
        imageToSave = [self addCaption:originalImage];
    }

    // Saves the image into the documents folder
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSString *todayDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_%@_%@.jpg",documentsDirectory,
                          todayDate,self.passedProjectName,self.passedYourName];
    NSString *fileCheck = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@_%@.jpg",todayDate,
                           self.passedProjectName,self.passedYourName];

    saveNumber = 0;
    while ([self checkImageFileName:fileCheck]) {
        saveNumber++;
        fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_%@_%@_%i.jpg",documentsDirectory,
                              todayDate,self.passedProjectName,self.passedYourName,saveNumber];
        fileCheck = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@_%@_%i.jpg",todayDate,
                     self.passedProjectName,self.passedYourName,saveNumber];
        //NSLog(@"File name was the same");
    }

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, 1)];
    [imageData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
    // Save the image to the Camera Roll
    //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (imageToSave, nil, nil , nil);
}
// Process for saving a video
if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
    == kCFCompareEqualTo) {//if it's a video
    //define the movie
    NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:
                            UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    //if possible, save in the camera roll
    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (
                                             moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
    }
}
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; //Dismiss the controller
[self.viewPhoto setImage:imageToSave]; //Assign the picture to the image view
```

} // end imagePickerController

```
- (BOOL)getUserCaption{

UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Great shot!" message:@"Please enter a caption for this photo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Save" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
alertTextField.placeholder = @"Enter caption";
//[alert show];
[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:TRUE];

return true;
```

}

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSLog(@"entered alertCAption");
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    NSLog(@"buttonIndex was 0");
    caption = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
    gotCaption = true;
    NSLog(@"%@",caption);
}
```

}

```
- (UIImage*)addCaption:(UIImage*)imageToSave
```

{

```
UIColor *textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];
CGFloat paddingX = 20.f;
CGFloat paddingY = 20.f;

// Compute rect to draw the text inside
CGSize imageSize = imageToSave.size;

NSDictionary *attr = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor, NSFontAttributeName: font};
CGSize textSize = [caption sizeWithAttributes:attr];
CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(imageSize.width - textSize.width - paddingX, imageSize.height - textSize.height - paddingY, textSize.width, textSize.height);

// Create the image
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
[imageToSave drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];

// Create the background for caption
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6);
// Add Filled Rectangle,
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(imageSize.width - textSize.width - paddingX-10, imageSize.height - textSize.height - paddingY-10, (textSize.width+20), (textSize.height+20)));

[caption drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(textRect) withAttributes:attr];

UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return resultImage;
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure if UIImagePickerController is designed to be dressed up. But you could certainly fall back to a lower level API and dress up the video feed.

Comment: Link to lower level API sample: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112